# How to redirect between subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess

I have site.com with htaccess file. How to write redirect:

from

https://subdomain.site.com/metal/blokiloki/wto-420132015-65/

to

https://subdomain.site.com/metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/

Tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)subdomain.site.com/metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1subdomain.site.com/metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/ [R=301,L]
```

UPDATE!

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^metal/blokiloki/wto-420132015-65/?$ 
https://%{HTTP_HOST}/metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Kindly do share your tried .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: So you are hitting link `https://subdomain.site.com/metal/blokiloki/wto-420132015-65/` in browser and you want it to be changed to `https://subdomain.site.com/metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/`? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes, I want the next scenario: I hit link https://subdomain.site.com/metal/blokiloki/wto-420132015-65/ on my page and it must open this page https://subdomain.site.com/metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/

Comment: oh ok. In backend where is your htaaccess file and your actual files are pressent? And do you have other rules apart from these in your .htaccess file?

Comment: My htaccess file and all other files are in the same folder "public_html". There are a lot of rules in the file.
For example:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.site.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

Comment: Ok, could you please post your complete htaccess file also in your question? You can replace actua domain names with sample name etc. Because we needed to see where to place it actually else it may mess up the things, cheers.

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST} is subdomain.site.com only `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)subdomain\.site\.com$ RewriteRule ^/?metal/blokiloki/wto-420132015-65/?$ /metal/material/privodnye-bloki/wto-420132015-65/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Request you to please update question to make sure its been clearly visible, thank you.